# How to expand PS1?

Tags: bash, ps1

I have a shell script that runs the same command in several directories ([fgit](http://github.com/l0b0/fgit/blob/master/fgit.sh)). For each directory, I would like it to show the current prompt + the command which will be run there. How do I get the string that corresponds to the **decoded** (expanded)`PS1`? For example, my default PS1 is

```sh
${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\e[1;32m\]\u\[\e[0m\]@\[\e[1;32m\]\h\[\e[0m\]:\[\e[1;34m\]\w\[\e[0m\]$(__git_ps1 ' (%s)')$
```

and I'd like to echo the resulting prompt `username@hostname:/path$`, preferably (but not necessarily) with the nice colors. A cursory look at the Bash manual didn't reveal any definite answer, and `echo -e $PS1` only evaluates the colors.

Comment: My head hurts. I know you probably want to use the `eval echo` idiom, but I can't think how to get the colors safely through. (My prompt is even worse - I have it red/green based on exit status, so the escaped characters for colors have to be dealt with *after* the expansion.)

Comment: My guess at this point is that if we can find whatever will expand `\u` to `username`, it's easy peasy. But it's not documented (and I don't know enough C to dig into Bash).

Comment: It looks like the command to run is `expand_prompt_string` from subst.c in the Bash source tree. Now to figure out how to call that from within the script...

Comment: @I0b0: Oh, right, I forgot about the extra directives like `\u`. And... I'm not sure that expand_prompt_string is going to be accessible from the shell, unless you patch it. (Maybe you could compile it separately...)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since Bash 4.4 you can use the `@P` expansion:

First I put your prompt string in a variable `myprompt` using `read -r` and a quoted here-doc:

```
read -r myprompt <<'EOF'
${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\e[1;32m\]\u\[\e[0m\]@\[\e[1;32m\]\h\[\e[0m\]:\[\e[1;34m\]\w\[\e[0m\]$(__git_ps1 ' (%s)')$ 
EOF
```

To print the prompt (as it would be interpreted if it were `PS1`), use the expansion `${myprompt@P}`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${myprompt@P}"
gniourf@rainbow:~$
$
```

(In fact there are some `\001` and `\002` characters, coming from `\[` and `\]` that you can't see in here, but you can see them if you try to edit this post; you'll also see them in your terminal if you type the commands).

---

To get rid of these, the trick sent by Dennis Williamson on the bash mailing list is to use `read -e -p` so that these characters get interpreted by the readline library:

```
read -e -p "${myprompt@P}"
```

This will prompt the user, with the `myprompt` correctly interpreted.

To this post, Greg Wooledge answered that you might as well just strip the `\001` and `\002` from the string. This can be achieved like so:

```
myprompt=${myprompt@P}
printf '%s\n' "${myprompt//[$'\001'$'\002']}"
```

To this post, Chet Ramey answered that you could also turn off line editing altogether with `set +o emacs +o vi`. So this will do too:

```
( set +o emacs +o vi; printf '%s\n' "${myprompt@P}" )
```

Comment: Tested on Bash 4.4 RC1, and it kinda works. `printf '%s\n' "${PS1@P}"` prints my prompt exactly as it appears to me, but when I try to `printf '%q\n' "${PS1@P}"` I see the the username and host twice, and the path once with `~` and once with `/home/username`: `$'username\001\E[1m\002\001\E[33m\002^2\001\E(B\E[m\002@hostname:\001\E[1m\002\001\E[34m\002~/download/bash-4.4-rc1\001\E(B\E[m\002\001\E]0;username@hostname:/home/username/download/bash-4.4-rc1\a\002\n$ '`. Strange.

Comment: @lobo If you run `echo "$PS1"`, you'll see something like `\[\e]0;\u@\h:$PWD\a\]`. That sets the title for xterm-compatible terminals.

Comment: Using `PROMPTCOMMAND` to separate "things to do at prompt time" from "things to display in the prompt" is usually a good idea.

Answer (score 12):

One great advantage of open source software is that the source is, well, open :-)

Bash itself does not provide this functionality but there are various tricks you can use to provide a subset (such as substituting `\u` with `$USER` and so on). However, this requires a lot of duplication of functionality and ensuring that the code is kept in sync with whatever `bash` does in future.

If you want to get *all* the power of prompt variables (and you don't mind getting your hands dirty with a bit of coding (and, if you do mind, why are you here?)), it's easy enough to add to the shell itself.

If you download the code for `bash` (I'm looking at version 4.2), there's a `y.tab.c` file which contains the `decode_prompt_string()` function:

```
char *decode_prompt_string (string) char *string; { ... }
```

This is the function that evaluates the `PSx` variables for prompting. In order to allow this functionality to be provided to users of the shell itself (rather than just used *by* the shell), you can follow these steps to add an internal command `evalps1`.

First, change `support/mkversion.sh` so that you won't confuse it with a "real" `bash`, and so that the FSF can deny all knowledge for warranty purposes :-) Simply change one line (I added the `-pax` bit):

```
echo "#define DISTVERSION \"${float_dist}-pax\""
```

Second, change `builtins/Makefile.in` to add a new source file. This entails a number of steps.

(a) Add `$(srcdir)/evalps1.def` to the end of `DEFSRC`.

(b) Add `evalps1.o` to the end of `OFILES`.

(c) Add the required dependencies:

```
evalps1.o: evalps1.def $(topdir)/bashtypes.h $(topdir)/config.h \
           $(topdir)/bashintl.h $(topdir)/shell.h common.h
```

Third, add the `builtins/evalps1.def` file itself, this is the code that gets executed when you run the `evalps1` command:

```
This file is evalps1.def, from which is created evalps1.c.
It implements the builtin "evalps1" in Bash.

Copyright (C) 1987-2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

This file is part of GNU Bash, the Bourne Again SHell.

Bash is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

Bash is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with Bash.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

$PRODUCES evalps1.c

$BUILTIN evalps1
$FUNCTION evalps1_builtin
$SHORT_DOC evalps1
Outputs the fully interpreted PS1 prompt.

Outputs the PS1 prompt, fully evaluated, for whatever nefarious purposes
you require.
$END

#include <config.h>
#include "../bashtypes.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "../bashintl.h"
#include "../shell.h"
#include "common.h"

int
evalps1_builtin (list)
     WORD_LIST *list;
{
  char *ps1 = get_string_value ("PS1");
  if (ps1 != 0)
  {
    ps1 = decode_prompt_string (ps1);
    if (ps1 != 0)
    {
      printf ("%s", ps1);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The bulk of that is the GPL licence (since I modified it from `exit.def`) with a very simple function at the end to get and decode `PS1`.

Lastly, just build the thing in the top level directory:

```
./configure
make
```

The `bash` executable that appears can be renamed to `paxsh`, though I doubt it will ever become as prevalent as its ancestor :-)

And running it, you can see it in action:

```
pax> mv bash paxsh

pax> ./paxsh --version
GNU bash, version 4.2-pax.0(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

pax> ./paxsh

pax> echo $BASH_VERSION
4.2-pax.0(1)-release

pax> echo "[$PS1]"
[pax> ]

pax> echo "[$(evalps1)]"
[pax> ]

pax> PS1="\h: "

paxbox01: echo "[$PS1]"
[\h: ]

paxbox01: echo "[$(evalps1)]"
[paxbox01: ]
```

When you put one of the `PSx` variables into the prompt, echoing `$PS1` simply gives you the variable, while the `evalps1` command evaluates it and outputs the result.

Now, granted, making code changes to `bash` to add an internal command may be considered by some to be overkill but, if you want an perfect evaluation of `PS1`, it's certainly an option.

Comment: Cool! Might it be easier to use as a [dyamically-loadable builtin](http://cfajohnson.com/shell/articles/dynamically-loadable/) that any bash process could use?

Comment: @Andrew, I'm not sure DLBs get access to the code already in the shell, do they? The "command" has to be able to call `decode_prompt_string()`. I could be wrong about that (it happens more often than I care to admit to) but I though DLB had to be pretty well self-contained.

Comment: Yes, you’re right; my mistake. If you have an unstripped bash binary you could use some hacks to read the addresses of internal bash functions and variables from the symbol table, but the system bash is almost certainly stripped :/

Comment: The main problem I could see by using this method is: You have to run/use your own modified version of bash. With the high frequence bash sources have to be patched, you will have a lot of work in futur for maintaining your version up to date! (Until your patch may be intagrated in official bash sources)...

Comment: @F.Hauri, given the localisation of the changes required, it would be a simple matter to write a script to pull down updated source, make the mods, then compile the modified code. This is exactly what we do in Yocto distro builds (there's a `do_patch` step somewhere between `do_fetch` and `do_compile`). On the other hand, I tend to only update software when needed, not just because the devs think I should :-)

Comment: Calling `decode_prompt_string()` from a dynamically loaded builtin seemed to work for me. I asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50068834/can-bashs-c-functions-safely-be-called-from-dynamically-loadable-builtins to find out whether or not this is actually safe.

Comment: > *However, this requires a lot of duplication of functionality and ensuring that the code is kept in sync with whatever bash does in future.* This can be sidestepped by defining a prompt language that **you** control, which your own code compiles to Bash PS1 syntax, and to an expansion.

Answer (score 9):

Why don't you just process the `$PS1` escape substitutions yourself? A series of substitutions such as these:

```
p="${PS1//\\u/$USER}"; p="${p//\\h/$HOSTNAME}"
```

By the way, zsh has the ability to interpret prompt escapes.

```
print -P '%n@%m %d'
```

or

```
p=${(%%)PS1}
```

Comment: This works in limited cases, but a complete solution would require many substitutions, some of them involving more than just simple substitution based on existing variables (see `man bash`, section `PROMPTING`); also, the solution would have to be kept current should future bash versions introduce new `PS1` features.

Answer (score 5):

I like the idea of fixing Bash to make it better, and I appreciate paxdiablo's [verbose answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451993/echo-expanded-ps1/14231995#14231995) on how to patch Bash. I'll have a go sometime.

However, without patching Bash source-code, I have a one-liner hack that is both portable and doesn't duplicate functionality, because the workaround uses only Bash and its builtins.

```
x="$(PS1=\"$PS1\" echo -n | bash --norc -i 2>&1)"; echo "'${x%exit}'"
```

Note that there's something strange going on with `tty`'s and `stdio` seeing as this also works:

```
x="$(PS1=\"$PS1\" echo -n | bash --norc -i 2>&1 > /dev/null)"; echo "'${x%exit}'"
```

So although I don't understand what's going on with the `stdio` here, my hack is working for me on Bash 4.2, NixOS GNU/Linux. Patching the Bash source-code is definitely a more elegant solution, and it should be pretty easy and safe to do now that I'm using Nix.

Comment: +1, great workaround, though I also don't understand it fully - it seems that the child bash instance sends *everything* to *stderr*, possibly because of the competing concepts of executing-then-exiting a 'script' passed via stdin vs. a keep-open interactive shell. The question is whether that behavior can be relied upon in future versions. It does work on bash 4.x and can be made to work on 3.x as well (see below).

Comment: There are some issues, though: (a) by using a pipeline and only prepending `PS1="$PS1"` to the _first_ segment, the bash instance in the subshell won't see that variable (unless it happens to be _exported_); (b) it's better to call `"$BASH"` rather than `bash` so as to ensure that the _same_ executable as the current shell's is invoked; (c) did you mean to have the `‘` `’` chars in the final variable expansion? See below for a reformulation that addresses these issues.

Comment: The following variation addresses above issues; it also works on bash 3.x, where a spurious `bash: no job control in this shell` error message must be worked around. Note the trailing 'exit' is removed via a `sed` command inside the command substitution so as to make do with a _single_ command: `x=$(PS1="$PS1" "$BASH" --norc -i </dev/null 2>&1 | sed -n '${s/^\(.*\)exit$/\1/p;}')`.

Comment: Finally, it's worth stating the _limitations_ of this solution: (a) it won't work if your prompt string _references non-exported shell variables and/or calls non-exported shell functions_ - you can work around that by exporting what's needed, but that's clearly not a generic solution; (b) it won't work if you prompt string *modifies* variables (such as a command sequence counter), because a child process cannot modify its parent's environment; there's no good workaround that I'm aware of.

Comment: @mklement0 This almost works for me, except for the fact that there seems to be length limit of 82(?) characters, after which the beginning of the line is overwritten, mangling prompts such as `FIRST_PART_LAST_PART$` to `ART$T_PART_LAST_P`. Any idea how this could be circumvented? Thanks!

Comment: @DavidNemeskey: From what I can tell, there's no length limit per se; what you describe sounds more like you have a `\r` (CR) char. in there somewhere. You can simulate your symptom with the following: `echo $'FIRST_PART_LAST_P\rART$'`. I suggest examining your output with `... | od -c`. I have noticed one strange thing in Bash 3.x, though: an invisible terminal escape sequence is prepended to the output, which can be suppressed by temporarily resetting the `TERM` variable, which gives us `TERM= PS1="$PS1" "$BASH" --norc -i </dev/null 2>&1 | sed -n '$ s/^\(.*\)exit$/\1/p'`.

Comment: @mklement0 There is a `\r` in it, but that only appears when the length of the prompt reaches 81 characters. Then, that character is duplicated, and a `\r` is added between them (so my last example was wrong, it should have been `PART$T_PART_LAST_P`). I tried resetting the `TERM` variable, but then the output became `< 001 ... 001 \r \n` (a `<` followed by about 80 `001`'s).

Comment: @DavidNemeskey That's strange - I have no explanation. I suggest you create a new question and provide more details.

Answer (score 3):

## Two answer: "Pure bash" and "bash + sed"

### Intro

Of course, from version 4.4 of [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), as [gniourf_gniourf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815797/gniourf-gniourf) correctly [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37137981/1765658), you have to use ***parameter transformation***:

```
ExpPS1=${PS1@P}
echo ${ExpPS1@Q}
$'\001\E]0;user@host: ~\a\002user@host:~$ '
```

See `man -Pless\ +/parameter\\\ transformation bash`

But for older bash, or even just for playing with *strings* and *variables*...

### [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) prompt expansion, using `bash` + `sed`

There is my hack:

```
ExpPS1="$(bash --rcfile <(echo "PS1='$PS1'") -i <<<'' 2>&1 |
              sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/^\(.*\n\)*\(.*\)\n\2exit$/\2/p;d')"
```

Explanation:

Running `bash --rcfile <(echo "PS1='$PS1'") -i <<<'' 2>&1`

May return something like:

> ```
> user@host:~$ 
> user@host:~$ exit
> ```

The `sed` command will then

- take all lines into one buffer (`:a;$!{N;ba};`), then
- replace `<everything, terminated by end-of-line><prompt>end-of-line<prompt>exit` by `<prompt>`. (`s/^\(.*\n\)*\(.*\)\n\2exit$/\2/`).

  - where `<everything, terminated by end-of-line>` become `\1`
  - and `<prompt>` become `\2`.

#### Test case:

```
while ExpPS1="$(bash --rcfile <(echo "PS1='$PS1'") -i <<<'' 2>&1 |
          sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/^\(.*\n\)*\(.*\)\n\2exit$/\2/p;d')"
    read -rp "$ExpPS1" && [ "$REPLY" != exit ] ;do
    eval "$REPLY"
  done
```

From there, you're in a kind of pseudo interactive shell (without readline facilities, but that's does not matter)...

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cd /tmp
ubuntu@ubuntu:/tmp$ PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\e[1;32m\]\u\[\e[0m\]@\[\e[1;32m\]\h\[\e[0m\]:\[\e[1;34m\]\w\[\e[0m\]$ "
ubuntu@ubuntu:/tmp$
```

(Last line print both `ubuntu` in green, `@`, `:` and `$`  in black and path (`/tmp`) in blue)

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/tmp$ exit
ubuntu@ubuntu:/tmp$ od -A n -t c <<< $ExpPS1 
 033   [   1   ;   3   2   m   u   b   u   n   t   u 033   [   0
   m   @ 033   [   1   ;   3   2   m   u   b   u   n   t   u 033
   [   0   m   : 033   [   1   ;   3   4   m   ~ 033   [   0   m
   $  \n
```

### Pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

Simple and quick:

```
ExpPS1="$(bash --rcfile <(echo "PS1='$PS1'") -i <<<'' 2>&1)"
mapfile ExpPS1 <<<"${ExpPS1%exit}"
ExpPS1=( "${ExpPS1[*]::${#ExpPS1[@]}/2}" )
```

Then now

```
declare -p ExpPS1
declare -a ExpPS1=([0]=$'\E]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~\aubuntu@ubuntu:~$ \n')
```

or

```
echo ${ExpPS1@Q}
$'\E]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~\aubuntu@ubuntu:~$ \n'
```

Quick test with multiline prompts:

```
ExpPS1="$(bash --rcfile <(echo "PS1='Test string\n$(date)\n$PS1'"
    ) -i <<<'' 2>&1)";
mapfile ExpPS1 <<<"${ExpPS1%exit}"
ExpPS1=( "${ExpPS1[*]::${#ExpPS1[@]}/2}" )    

echo ${ExpPS1@Q}
$'Test string\r\n Sat Jan 9 19:23:47 CET 2021\r\n \E]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~\aubuntu@ubuntu:~$ \n'
```

Or

```
od -A n -t c  <<<${ExpPS1}
   T   e   s   t       s   t   r   i   n   g  \r  \n       S   a
   t       J   a   n           9       1   9   :   2   6   :   3
   9       C   E   T       2   0   2   1  \r  \n     033   ]   0
   ;   u   b   u   n   t   u   @   u   b   u   n   t   u   :    
   ~  \a   u   b   u   n   t   u   @   u   b   u   n   t   u   :
   ~   $      \n  \n
```

Note you could add a little test to ensure string is correct:

```
ExpPS1="$(bash --rcfile <(echo "PS1='$PS1'") -i <<<'' 2>&1)"
mapfile ExpPS1 <<<"${ExpPS1%exit}"
[ "${ExpPS1[*]::${#ExpPS1[@]}/2}" = "${ExpPS1[*]: -${#ExpPS1[@]}/2}" ] ||
    echo WARNING: First half seem not match last half string.
ExpPS1=( "${ExpPS1[*]::${#ExpPS1[@]}/2}" )
```

Comment: both methods was tested with `PS1='Test string\n\D{%a %d %b %Y, %Hh, %Mm, %Ss.}\n\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '`

Answer (score 1):

One more possibility: without editing bash source code, using `script` utility (part of `bsdutils` package on ubuntu):

```
$ TEST_PS1="\e[31;1m\u@\h:\n\e[0;1m\$ \e[0m"
$ RANDOM_STRING=some_random_string_here_that_is_not_part_of_PS1
$ script /dev/null <<-EOF | awk 'NR==2' RS=$RANDOM_STRING
PS1="$TEST_PS1"; HISTFILE=/dev/null
echo -n $RANDOM_STRING
echo -n $RANDOM_STRING
exit
EOF
<prints the prompt properly here>
```

`script` command generates a file specified & the output is also shown on stdout. If filename is omitted, it generates a file called typescript.

Since we are not interested in the log file in this case, filename is specified as `/dev/null`. Instead the stdout of the script command is passed to awk for further processing.

1. The entire code can also be encapsulated into a function.
2. Also, the output prompt can also be assigned to a variable.
3. This approach also supports parsing of `PROMPT_COMMAND`...

Comment: Interesting approach, but - as you hint at by mentioning Ubuntu - it's limited to platforms running _GNU_ utilities (other platforms, such as OSX, have utilities of the same name, but they behave differently), whereas `bash` runs on many more platforms. Also note that `script` translates `\n` in the prompt string to `\r\n`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Expand it with `ps=${ps@P}` (bash 4.4)
2. Remove between `\x01` and `\x02` (created by bash replacing the `\[` and `\]` placeholder.
3. Check all characters left

```sh
ps1_size(){
  # Ref1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451993/how-to-expand-ps1
  >&2 echo -e "\nP0: Raw"
  local ps=$PS1
  echo -n "$ps" | xxd >&2 

  >&2 echo -e "\nP1: Expanding (require bash 4.4)"
  ps=${ps@P}
  echo -n "$ps" | xxd >&2 

  >&2 echo -e "\nP2: Removing everything 01 and 02"
  shopt -s extglob
  ps=${ps//$'\x01'*([^$'\x02'])$'\x02'}
  echo -n "$ps" | xxd >&2 

  >&2 echo -e "\nP3: Checking"
  if [[ "$ps" =~ [\x07\x1b\x9c] ]]; then
    # Check if escape inside
    # 07 => BEL
    # 1b => ESC
    # 9C => ST
    >&2 echo 'Warning: There is an escape code in your PS1 which is not betwwen \[ \]'
    >&2 echo "Tip: put \[ \] around your escape codes (ctlseqs + associated parameters)"
    echo -n "$ps" | xxd >&2
  # Check printable characters <= 20 .. 7e, and newline
  # -- Remove the trailing 0x0a (BEL)
  elif [[ "$ps" =~ [^[:graph:][:space:]] ]]; then
    >&2 echo 'Warning: There is a non printable character in PS1 which is not between \[ \]'
    >&2 echo "Tip: put \[ \] around your escape codes (ctlseqs + associated parameters)"
    echo "$ps"
    echo -n "$ps" | xxd >&2 
  fi

  # Echo result
  echo -n "${#ps}"
}

ps1_size
```

Should output something like this:

```
~/Software/Bash/Mouse (master)$ source ../ps1_size.sh

P0: Raw
00000000: 5c5b 5c65 5d30 3b60 7061 7273 655f 7469  \[\e]0;`parse_ti
00000010: 746c 6560 5c30 3037 5c5d 5c5b 5c65 5b33  tle`\007\]\[\e[3
00000020: 326d 5c5d 5c77 205c 5b5c 655b 3333 6d5c  2m\]\w \[\e[33m\
00000030: 5d60 7061 7273 655f 6769 745f 6272 616e  ]`parse_git_bran
00000040: 6368 605c 5b5c 655b 306d 5c5d 2420       ch`\[\e[0m\]$

P1: Expanding (require bash 4.4)
00000000: 011b 5d30 3b7e 2f53 6f66 7477 6172 652f  ..]0;~/Software/
00000010: 4261 7368 2f4d 6f75 7365 0702 011b 5b33  Bash/Mouse....[3
00000020: 326d 027e 2f53 6f66 7477 6172 652f 4261  2m.~/Software/Ba
00000030: 7368 2f4d 6f75 7365 2001 1b5b 3333 6d02  sh/Mouse ..[33m.
00000040: 286d 6173 7465 7229 011b 5b30 6d02 2420  (master)..[0m.$

P2: Removing everything 01 and 02
00000000: 7e2f 536f 6674 7761 7265 2f42 6173 682f  ~/Software/Bash/
00000010: 4d6f 7573 6520 286d 6173 7465 7229 2420  Mouse (master)$

P3: Checking
32~/Software/Bash/Mouse (master)$
```

If some control characters are present, you can remove it as stated in this [stackoverflow: Removing ANSI color codes from text stream](https://superuser.com/questions/380772/removing-ansi-color-codes-from-text-stream).
I used the following to remove SCI and OSC in [github: mouse_xterm](https://github.com/tinmarino/mouse_xterm/blob/master/mouse.sh).

```sh
  # Sanitize, in case
  ps=$(LC_ALL=C sed '
    # Safety
    s/\x01\|\x02//g;
    # Safety Remove OSC https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h3-Operating-System-Commands
    # 20 .. 7e => printable characters
    # 07 => BEL
    # 9C => ST
    # 1b 5C => ESC + BS
    s/\x1b\][0-9;]*[\x20-\x7e]*\([\x07\x9C]\|\x1b\\\)//g;
    # Safety: Remove all escape sequences https://superuser.com/questions/380772/removing-ansi-color-codes-from-text-stream
    s/\x1b\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z]//g;
  ' <<< "$ps")
```

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Comment: Hi @cigien, thank you for the comment. I delayed and explained, the link to my own code. The referenced code shows a usage of the presented function.