# bash: How to evaluate PS1, PS2, ...?

Tags: bash, evaluate, ps1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Echo expanded PS1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451993/echo-expanded-ps1)

Is there any way to 'evaluate' `PS1`, `PS2`, etc from within a bash script?

Although, I can use alternate means to get all elements of my current `PS1`, I would really like to be able to reuse its definition instead of using these alternate means.

For example,

```
=====================================
 PS1 element -->     Alternate means
=====================================
 \u          -->     $USER
 \h          -->     $HOSTNAME
 \w          -->     $PWD
 ...
=====================================
```

I could very well use the 'alternate means' column in my script, but I don't want to. In my `PS1`, I, for example, use bold blue color via terminal escape sequences which I'd like to be able to simply reuse by evaluating `PS1`.

Comment: Maybe other people know, but I have no idea what you're talking about. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Do you wish to eval the $PS1, $PS2 ? Or do you want to attribute values to those variables inside your script?

Comment: Suppose there's a function or command called `evaluate`. What the result of `evaluate PS1` should be?

Comment: @Gangadhar Yes, I want to `eval` `$PS1`, `$PS2` etc. No, I do not want to attribute values to those variables from inside my script.

Comment: @n.m. The result of this hypothetical `evaluate` should be **whatever** I see as my prompt on each `ENTER`.

Comment: All - though I have marked pax's answer as the final one, my search for a better final answer is not over yet. Would welcome alternate ideas, if any.

Comment: Aha, got it. Try this: `myps1=$(echo -e "PROMPT_COMMAND=\n" | bash -i 2>&1  | head -2 | tail -1)` — note this will contain any prompt colorizing escape sequences.

Comment: @n.m. Not sure what you mean. What is `PROMPT_COMMAND`? You assign it a value but never use it! When I ran just the portion within the `$(...)`, I got a blank output. That is, issuing the whole command (which you wrote above) followed by an `echo ":$myps1:"` gave me `::` as output. Did you try it yourself? My `PS1` is set to `'\[\033[0;34m\]\u@\h $? \w\n$\[\033[0m\]'`; could you try what you're suggesting as a solution on this value of `PS1` and then get back? Many thanks, btw.

Comment: PROMPT_COMMAND is something that has to be *unset* for this code. Look it up. Assigning an empty string is the simplest way. Yes I tried the code and it works for me. Perhaps different bash versions? Try removing the head and tail commands and see what happens.

Comment: I don't actually consider this a duplicate. OP specifically stated that the alternate means were not an option which I think makes this unique enough to justify it. Especially since the accepted answer as the other question is to _use_ those alternate means. Voting to reopen but I'll copy (with mods) my answer to the other question for completeness.

Comment: `echo ${PS1@P}` seems to do the trick

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One great advantage of open source software is that the source is, well, open :-)

If you download the code for `bash` (I'm looking at version 4.2), there's a `y.tab.c` file which contains the `decode_prompt_string()` function:

```
char *decode_prompt_string (string) char *string; { ... }
```

You can try to extract that (along with any needed support routines and build an executable which did the job for you. Although, from a cursory try, those support routines seem to be a lot, so this may be a hard task.

---

Other than that, you can probably "trick" `bash` into expanding it for you with something like:

```
expPS1=$(echo xyzzyplughtwisty | bash -i 2>&1
         | grep xyzzyplughtwisty
         | head -1
         | sed 's/xyzzyplughtwisty//g')
```

Now I've put that across multiple lines for readability but it was done on one line.

What this does is run an interactive instance of `bash`, passing (what hopefully is) an invalid command.

Because it's interactive, it prints the prompt so I grab the first line with the command string on it and remove that command string. What's left over should be the prompt.

On my system, this is what I get:

```
pax> expPS1=$(echo xyzzyplughtwisty | bash -i 2>&1 | grep xyzzyplughtwisty | head -1 | sed 's/xyzzyplughtwisty//g')

pax> echo "[$expPS1]"
[pax> ]

pax>
```

However, this has problems with multi-line prompts and will actually give you your regular prompt rather than the current shell one.

---

If you want to do it *properly,* it may involve adding a little bit to `bash` itself. Here are the steps to add an internal command `evalps1`.

First, change `support/mkversion.sh` so that you won't confuse it with a "real" `bash`, and so that the FSF can deny all knowledge for warranty purposes :-) Simply change one line (I added the `-pax` bit):

```
echo "#define DISTVERSION \"${float_dist}-pax\""
```

Second, change `builtins/Makefile.in to add a new source file. This entails a number of steps.

(a) Add `$(srcdir)/evalps1.def` to the end of `DEFSRC`.

(b) Add `evalps1.o` to the end of `OFILES`.

(c) Add the required dependencies:

```
evalps1.o: evalps1.def $(topdir)/bashtypes.h $(topdir)/config.h \
           $(topdir)/bashintl.h $(topdir)/shell.h common.h
```

Third, add the `builtins/evalps1.def` file itself, this is the code that gets executed when you run the `evalps1` command:

```
This file is evalps1.def, from which is created evalps1.c.
It implements the builtin "evalps1" in Bash.

Copyright (C) 1987-2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

This file is part of GNU Bash, the Bourne Again SHell.

Bash is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

Bash is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with Bash.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

$PRODUCES evalps1.c

$BUILTIN evalps1
$FUNCTION evalps1_builtin
$SHORT_DOC evalps1
Outputs the fully interpreted PS1 prompt.

Outputs the PS1 prompt, fully evaluated, for whatever nefarious purposes
you require.
$END

#include <config.h>
#include "../bashtypes.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "../bashintl.h"
#include "../shell.h"
#include "common.h"

int
evalps1_builtin (list)
     WORD_LIST *list;
{
  char *ps1 = get_string_value ("PS1");
  if (ps1 != 0)
  {
    ps1 = decode_prompt_string (ps1);
    if (ps1 != 0)
    {
      printf ("%s", ps1);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The bulk of that is the GPL licence (since I modified it from `exit.def`) with a very simple function at the end to get and decode `PS1`.

Lastly, just build the thing in the top level directory:

```
./configure
make
```

The `bash` that appears can be renamed to `paxsh`, though I doubt it will ever become as prevalent as its ancestor :-)

And running it, you can see it in action:

```
pax> mv bash paxsh

pax> ./paxsh --version
GNU bash, version 4.2-pax.0(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

pax> ./paxsh

pax> echo $BASH_VERSION
4.2-pax.0(1)-release

pax> echo "[$PS1]"
[pax> ]

pax> echo "[$(evalps1)]"
[pax> ]

pax> PS1="\h: "

paxbox01: echo "[$PS1]"
[\h: ]

paxbox01: echo "[$(evalps1)]"
[paxbox01: ]
```

Now, granted, making code changes to `bash` to add an internal command may be considered overkill by some but, if you want an accurate evaluation of `PS1`, it's certainly an option.

Comment: Are you sure you tried it on your system? When I tried and echoed $expPS1, I got "bash: : command not found..." as the value. Note also that head -1 may not work when you have a multi-line prompt.  Also, I'm printing my prompt in bold-blue color. This is the very reason I posted this question: I would like to retain my PS1 fully without duplicating its elements in any shape or form. Fyi, my PS1 is set to: '`\[\033[0;34m\]\u@\h $? \w\n$\[\033[0m\]`'. While I definitely like the ingenuity of your solution, it is very slow: there's 1-2 second gap before I see any result at all.

Comment: That's quite a laundry list of problems you have :-) (1) Yes, I tried in on my system, that last bit is an actual transcript. (2) Yes, `head -1` won't work for multiline prompts, you'll have to be a bit more ingenious for that and it'll probably require foreknowledge of the line count or pre-processing of `PS1` counting `\n` sections.  (3) I'm not sure what the problem is with color although you may have to force your `TERM` setting. (4) I can't vouch for the speed, that depends on how long it takes to start the shell. If the second solution is inadequate, you may need to look at the first.

Comment: But I suspect it may be _more_ effort, though at least it should solve those problems. You can even write a script which does similar things to the C code to translate an arbitrary `PS1`.

Comment: "That's quite a laundry list of problems you have :-)" Was just providing you feedback, not expecting you to work on this 'laundry list'. Have +1'ed your answer already, appreciate your taking the time to write instead of (quite justifiably) working on your own laundry list of things which people usually have :-) especially on weekends :-))