# How to simulate two consecutive ENTER key presses for a command in a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

[EDITED]
It can be considered as an extension to [this question][1].
`echo | command` 
The above command can be used to supply one 'ENTER' character to the command's first input request.

How can i supply the next 'ENTER' character to the same command in its second input request.

Please comment if any other details are required.

Am giving the specific example which i want to implement.
I need to run `SSH-keyGen` commmand in my shell script.
It will ask for following inputs:

1. Enter the target file name
2. Enter the pass phrase
3. Enter the pass phrase again

How can we pass these three inputs to the command?

I tried with,

```
echo -ne "\n \n"| ssh-keygen  //which is passing two new lines for the first input request only.
```

and
`echo -ne "\n"|(echo -ne "\n"|ssh-keygen)// but still no positive result`

Note: Am avoiding the input file name request in the above two command, just to make the things simple

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For example, you can use either

```
echo -e "\n"
```

or

```
echo -en "\n\n"
```

The `-e` option tells `echo` to interpret escape characters. `\n` is the newline (enter) character. So the first prints a newline due to `\n`, and then another one since `echo` usually appends a newline.

The `-n` option tells `echo` to suppress adding an implicit newline. To get two newlines, you thus need to specify two `\n`.

**Edit:**

The problem here is that `ssh-keygen` is special. Due to security considerations, the passphrase is not read from standard input but directly from the terminal! To provide a passphrase (even an empty one) you need to use the `-P` option. Since you then only need one ENTER (for the file path prompt), this command should work:

```
echo | ssh-keygen -P ''
```

(note the two `'` with no space in between: they are important!)

Comment: It is not working @DarkDust . It is taking two new lines for the first input request only.

Comment: First of all, you've stated in your edit that you've used `echo "\n \n"`: that cannot work, you're missing the `-e` option. Next, `ssh-keygen` is special. Due to security considerations, the passphrase is not read from stdin but directly from the terminal! To provide a passphrase (even an empty one) you need to use the `-P` option: `echo | ssh-keygen -P ''` (note the two `'` with not space in between: they are important!)

Comment: I tried with -ne option only, I missed it to mention here( I added it now).
"ssh-keygen -P '' " had solved my issue. Thanks very much.So here, because of the command i was using, it became an issue and not because of the way i was giving input .
Can you add the same thing in the answer, so that i can select it as the answer.

Comment: This ssh-keygen trick was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The general solution is to use [the `yes` command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/yes):

```
yes '' | command
```

`yes` will repeatedly output the string specified on the command line with a newline appended. If you run it with an empty string as an argument, it'll output an endless string of newlines.

Answer (score 3):

How about a heredoc with 2 empty lines:

```
command <<END


END
```

or use printf

```
printf "\n\n" | command
```

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at expect:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
#set timeout 10
set clientName [lindex $argv 0];
set hostName [lindex $argv 1];
set passWord [lindex $argv 2];

spawn ssh "$hostName";
expect "Password:";
send "$passWord\r";
expect "$hostName";
```

Answer (score 1):

---

Solutions like `echo -e "\n\n\n\n\n"` will simulate `ENTER` by echo empty line only, without shell `prompt`.

will see:

```sh
➜  ~ echo -e "\n\n\n\n\n"






➜  ~
```

---

But if you want to simulate `ENTER` with shell `prompt`, here is my solution(define a function named `entern`):

zsh:

```sh
entern () {
      if [ "$1" ]; then
        for i in $(seq $1); do echo "${(%%)PS1}"; done
      else
        for i in $(seq 10); do echo "${(%%)PS1}"; done
      fi
}
```

Bash 4.4+:

```sh
entern () {
      if [ "$1" ]; then
        for i in $(seq 1 $1); do echo "${PS1@P}"; done
      else
        for i in $(seq 1 10); do echo "${PS1@P}"; done
      fi
}
```

> see: [How to print current bash prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56267057/2752670)

Use:

```sh
➜  ~ entern 5
```

will see:

```sh
➜  ~ entern 5 
➜  ~ 
➜  ~ 
➜  ~ 
➜  ~ 
➜  ~ 
➜  ~
```

default 10 times:

```sh
➜  ~ entern 
➜  ~ 
➜  ~ 
➜  ~ 
➜  ~ 
➜  ~ 
➜  ~ 
➜  ~ 
➜  ~ 
➜  ~ 
➜  ~ 
➜  ~
```