# Simulate "ENTER" key press in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, keyboard, automation

I want to automate the run of the `./configure` command. When I normally run it, every time I have to press enter. I want to run this command from a shell script and I don't want it to wait for a user to press enter at each prompt for path. How do I achieve this ? I am using Ubuntu machine with bash shell. Thanks.

```
mdt-inference@ubuntu:~/MDT/mdst-libreoffice$ ./configure 
Path to Office installation? [/usr/lib/libreoffice] 
Path to Office SDK installation? [/usr/lib/libreoffice/sdk]
```

Note : I tried the below link but it does not work.
[How to simulate two consecutive ENTER key presses for a command in a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30712126/how-to-simulate-two-consecutive-enter-key-presses-for-a-command-in-a-bash-script)

I have used "yes" command already but when I run ./configure there are multiple prompts which are more than two. When I use `"yes"`, it just supplies argument to the first prompt only

Comment: Are you saying that you are unable to pass the values as command line arguments?

Answer (score 1):

`yes` command can be used here (with just 2 enter key)

```
yes " " | head -2 | ./configure
```

In general, this should work.

```
yes | ./configure
```

Comment: I tried this already but when I run ./configure there are multiple prompts which are more than two. when I use yes, it just supplies argument to the first prompt only

Comment: Try with   yes "  " | ./configure

Answer (score 0):

You might check out the cram Python package:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cram

It's designed for straightforward automation of command-line apps, and I've been pleasantly surprised by how well it's worked for my needs so far.