# echo $PS1 in script

Tags: bash, shell, ps1

Silly question, but since I'm such a newbie at Linux OS, I'm having trouble to make this simple script to echo the result of `PS1`.

If I type `echo $PS1` in bash, it shows me the result, but not in the script. It returns blank.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
ps1=$(echo $PS1) 
echo $ps1
```

Any tips for a begginer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ps1="$PS1"` is more efficient and more correct. `echo` isn't needed. *Always* quote your parameter expansions.

Comment: Try to do it with `eval` $PS1 and `sed`, as nicely answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22322879/how-to-print-current-bash-prompt/44090232#44090232

Answer (score 8):

Other answers are correct. If you add the `-i` flag to your shebang, that signals bash that it's supposed to be an interactive shell, so it will read your ~/.bashrc -- see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Invoking-Bash

```
#!/bin/bash -i
ps1="$PS1"
echo "$ps1"
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed to know today.

Answer (score 5):

`PS1` is a variable which is not "exported", so it is only visible within the shell, but not from any subprocess such as the script's.

Answer (score 4):

`PS1` is typically not exported, since it is usually defined in `.bashrc`, which is sourced by every shell that would need `PS1`. As such, it isn't inherited by the non-interactive shell that executes your script.

Answer (score 0):

try this script from the documentation ..this might help you :

PS1 – The value of this parameter is used as the primary prompt string. The default value is \u@\h \W\$ .

$ echo $PS1     Sample output:  [\u@\h \W]$

```
\a : an ASCII bell character (07)
\d : the date in “Weekday Month Date” format (e.g., “Tue May 26”)
\e : an ASCII escape character (033)
\h : the hostname up to the first ‘.’
\H : the hostname
\j : the number of jobs currently managed by the shell
\l : the basename of the shellâ€™s terminal device name
\n : newline
\r : carriage return
\u : the username of the current user
\v : the version of bash (e.g., 2.00)
\V : the release of bash, version + patch level (e.g., 2.00.0)
\w : the current working directory, with $HOME abbreviated with a tilde
\W : the basename of the current working directory, with $HOME abbreviated with a tilde
```

Examples:

PS1="\d \h $ "      Sample output:  Sat Jun 02 server $

PS1="[\d \t \u@\h:\w ] $ "      Sample output:  [Sat Jun 02 14:24:12 vivek@server:~ ] $

Comment: hi Piyush, does not answer the question. please try to stay more on topic ^_^