# Getting text at beginning of command line

Tags: sh

In the following:

```
[09:15:22] /tools # pwd
/tools
[09:15:23] /tools # echo foo
foo
[09:15:27] /tools #
```

I want to read everything preceding the "#" (I'll call it the signature for now). The signature is auto-filled by the shell on every line where a user can input text.

I tried looking through `uname` without luck, and I've spent a good deal of time trying to find the proper name for this "signature" without success. Is there a way to do this (or, does anyone know the correct name for what I'm trying to read)?

Comment: That's called a *prompt*. It *prompts* the user for input.

Comment: The name is PS1 prompt. There are multiple.

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22322879/how-to-print-current-bash-prompt basically do this: `echo "'${PS1@P}'"`

Comment: My question looks to be a duplicate. Thanks for your clarification!