# How to get bash PROMPT?

Tags: linux, bash

We can use `echo $PS1` to view

```
test@testauto:~$ echo $PS1
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
test@testauto:~$
```

But what I want is "test@testauto:~$" not "[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w$"

How can I get it?

Comment: Just an aside, I always found the user prompt of `"\[\e[38;5;244m\]\D{%R}\[\e[38;5;32m\] \h:\w> \[\e[0m\]"` and a root prompt of `"\[\e[1;34m\][\[\e[38;5;203m\]\A \[\e[1;34m\]\h\[\e[38;5;197m\]:\w\[\e[1;34m\]] # \[\e[0m\]"` helpful. (256 color xterm) In addition to providing the time, they also provide the current path information in a form that can be used with `rsync`, `scp`, etc... E.g. user prompt of `00:48 wizard:~/tmpd> ` and root prompt (same location) `[00:48 wizard:/home/david/tmpd] # `

Comment: @GavinHunte21 : You tagged your question as _shell_, i.e. POSIX shell. See [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) for an explanation what you can put into `PS1`. It is not clear to me, how your question fits into the idea of POSIX shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Bash

```
echo "${PS1@P}"
```

For ZSH

```
echo "${(%%)PS1}"
```

You can find more about this in this thread: [How to print current bash prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22322879/how-to-print-current-bash-prompt)

Comment: I tested it on Ubuntu and the result was as expected.  
I tested it on an embedded device which using busybox and it failed.  
`test_aut:~ # echo "${PS1@P}"
/bin/sh: syntax error: bad substitution
test_aut:~ # ls -al /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     0                7 May 25 05:14 /bin/sh -> busybox`   Any comments? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @GavinHunter21 this is because busybox is not using bash or zsh. According tho this thread https://serverfault.com/questions/241959/whats-the-busybox-default-shell its some derivative of ash. I'm not familiar with busybox but after taking a look at the code I'm not sure if it supports that.