# Bash 4.4 prompt escape for number of jobs currently running

Tags: bash, special-characters, operator-keyword, parameter-expansion

I stumbled across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38774355/how-to-parallelize-for-loop-in-bash-limiting-number-of-processes) where user [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) proposed in his answer the usage of `\j` (as mentioned in the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html#Controlling-the-Prompt)) to retrieve the current running count of background jobs.
Basically it boils down to

```
num_jobs="\j"
echo ${num_jobs@P}
```

Can anyone enlighten me on what is going on here exactly? E.g.

- why `${\j@P}` is not working and
- what `@P` is doing exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like any parameter expansion, you have to supply the name of a parameter, not an arbitrary string. `\j` isn't the name of a parameter; it's the text you want to get *from* a parameter expansion.

After the parameter has been expanded, `@P` further subjects the result to prompt expansion, so that `\j` is replaced by the number of jobs.

```
$ num_jobs="\j"
$ echo "${num_jobs}"
\j
$ echo "${num_jobs@P}"
0
```

Comment: Thanks! I searched through the bash manual but could not find @P anywhere. Where is this described?

Comment: In the `man` page, it's at the end of the Parameter Expansion section, headed by `${parameter@operator}`. The various operators are listed without the prefixed `@`, though. Search for "Parameter transformation" instead.

Comment: [Got it](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)! Very neat trick this is!

Answer (score 1):

The part before the `@` is the name of the parameter you're trying to expand, it can't be a string you want to modify somehow. And `@P` is a parameter expansion introduced in Bash 4.4 (see [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)):

> `${parameter@operator}`
>
> The expansion is either a transformation of the value of *`parameter`*
>   or information about parameter itself, depending on the value of
>   *`operator`*. Each operator is a single letter:
>
> `P`
>
> The expansion is a string that is the result of expanding the value of
>   *`parameter`* as if it were a prompt string (see [Controlling the Prompt](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Controlling-the-Prompt)).