# C++ Function to Determine PS1

Tags: c++, function, command-prompt, prompt

I'd like to find a c++ function that (if the program is run from the command prompt) decodes the user's current default prompt string (generally just PS1) and stores it as a string variable.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451993/echo-expanded-ps1), but I also found it pretty confusing and am not even sure it's the same question. Any advice?

Comment: I'm sure this is exactly the same question and the answer unfortunately is: "It is hard and hacky."

Comment: `getenv("PS1")`? To get it "decoded", you'd have to know what shell the user is using and exactly how the things in `PS1` get expanded, for which there is likely not a single universal solution...