# Customizing bash completion output: each suggestion on a new line

Tags: bash, unix, customization, bash-completion

When you type something, you often use bash autocompletion: you start writing a command, for example, and you type `TAB` to get the rest of the word.

As you have probably noticed, when multiple choices match your command, bash displays them like this :

```
foobar@myserv:~$ admin-
admin-addrsync         admin-adduser          admin-delrsync         admin-deluser          admin-listsvn
admin-addsvn           admin-chmod            admin-delsvn           admin-listrsync
```

I'm looking for a solution to display each possible solution on a new line, similar to the last column on a `ls -l`. Ever better, **it would be perfect** if I could apply a rule like this: *"if you find less than 10 suggestions, display them one by line, if more => actual display"*.

Comment: Are you looking to do this for a specific custom completion you're working on, or are you looking to change this behavior _globally_?

Comment: I'm interested in both, actually !

Comment: I will accept @mklement0 's answer in a few days, but if ANYONE find a way to change this behaviour globally (ie, control the output format of bash completions), let me now, I'm really interested in !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**`bash` prior to version 4.2 doesn't allow any control over the *output format* of completions**, unfortunately.

<sup>Bash 4.2+ allows switching to 1-suggestion-per-line output *globally*, as explained in [Grisha Levit's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42215468/45375), which also links to a [clever workaround](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/344773/22523) to achieve a *per-completion-function* solution.</sup>

The following is a **tricky workaround** for a ***custom* completion.**
Solving this problem **generically**, for *all* defined completions, would be **much harder** (if there were a way to invoke `readline` functions directly, it might be easier, but I haven't found a way to do that).

To test the **proof of concept** below:

- Save to a file and *source* it (`. file`) in your interactive shell - this will:

  - define a command named `foo` (a shell function)
  - whose arguments complete based on matching filenames in the current directory.
  - (When `foo` is actually invoked, it simply prints its argument in diagnostic form.)
- Invoke as:
      `foo [fileNamePrefix]`, then press <kbd>tab</kbd>:

  - If between 2 and 9 files in the current directory match, you'll see the desired line-by-line display.
  - Otherwise (1 match or 10 or more matches), normal completion will occur.

**Limitations**:

- Completion only works properly when applied to the LAST argument on the command line being edited.
- When a completion is actually inserted in the command line (once the match is unambiguous), NO space is appended to it (this behavior is required for the workaround).
- Redrawing the prompt the first time after printing custom-formatted output may not work properly: Redrawing the command line including the prompt must be *simulated* and since there is no direct way to obtain an *expanded* version of the prompt-definition string stored in `$PS1`, a *workaround* (inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/24006864/45375) is used, which should work in *typical* cases, but is not foolproof.

**Approach**:

- Defines and assigns a custom completion shell function to the command of interest.
- The custom function determines the matches and, if their count is in the desired range, bypasses the normal completion mechanism and creates custom-formatted output.
- The custom-formatted output (each match on its own line) is sent directly to the terminal `>/dev/tty`, and then the prompt and command line are manually "redrawn" to mimic standard completion behavior.
- See the comments in the source code for implementation details.

```sh
# Define the command (function) for which to establish custom command completion.
# The command simply prints out all its arguments in diagnostic form.
foo() { local a i=0; for a; do echo "\$$((i+=1))=[$a]"; done; }

# Define the completion function that will generate the set of completions
# when <tab> is pressed.
# CAVEAT:
#  Only works properly if <tab> is pressed at the END of the command line,
#  i.e.,  if completion is applied to the LAST argument.
_complete_foo() {

  local currToken="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}" matches matchCount

  # Collect matches, providing the current command-line token as input.
  IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra matches <<<"$(compgen -A file "$currToken")"

  # Count matches.
  matchCount=${#matches[@]}

  # Output in custom format, depending on the number of matches.
  if (( matchCount > 1 && matchCount < 10 )); then

      # Output matches in CUSTOM format:
      # print the matches line by line, directly to the terminal.
    printf '\n%s' "${matches[@]}" >/dev/tty
      # !! We actually *must* pass out the current token as the result,
      # !! as it will otherwise be *removed* from the redrawn line,
      # !! even though $COMP_LINE *includes* that token.
      # !! Also, by passing out a nonempty result, we avoid the bell
      # !! signal that normally indicates a failed completion.
      # !! However, by passing out a single result, a *space* will
      # !! be appended to the last token - unless the compspec
      # !! (mapping established via `complete`) was defined with 
      # !! `-o nospace`.
    COMPREPLY=( "$currToken" )
      # Finally, simulate redrawing the command line.
        # Obtain an *expanded version* of `$PS1` using a trick
        # inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/24006864/45375.
        # !! This is NOT foolproof, but hopefully works in most cases.
    expandedPrompt=$(PS1="$PS1" debian_chroot="$debian_chroot" "$BASH" --norc -i </dev/null 2>&1 | sed -n '${s/^\(.*\)exit$/\1/p;}')
    printf '\n%s%s' "$expandedPrompt" "$COMP_LINE" >/dev/tty


  else # Just 1 match or 10 or more matches?

      # Perform NORMAL completion: let bash handle it by 
      # reporting matches via array variable `$COMPREPLY`.
    COMPREPLY=( "${matches[@]}" )    

  fi 

}

# Map the completion function (`_complete_foo`) to the command (`foo`).
# `-o nospace` ensures that no space is appended after a completion,
# which is needed for our workaround.
complete -o nospace -F _complete_foo -- foo
```

Comment: Great job @mklement0, really. That's a pitty we can change this behaviour globally, and that's suprised me (I thought we can do ANYTHING). About your answer, it nearly works : After the suggestions on each line, I get a "command not found" because of my colored PS1. You can try yourself by writing in your shell `PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '` and then test again your implementation - it crashed :(

Comment: @Ash_: Thanks for pointing out the prompt issue: it's nontrivial to fix, but I've put a workaround in place that should work with _typical_ prompt strings (including coloring), including yours - but it's not foolproof.

Answer (score 8):

`bash` 4.2+ (and, more generally, applications using `readline` 6.2+) support this with the use of the [**`completion-display-width`**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File-Syntax.html#index-comment_002dbegin) variable.

> The number of screen columns used to display possible matches when performing completion. The value is ignored if it is less than 0 or greater than the terminal screen width. **A value of 0 will cause matches to be displayed one per line.** The default value is -1.

Run the following to set the behavior for all completions<sup>1</sup> for your current session:

```
bind 'set completion-display-width 0'
```

Or modify your `~/.inputrc`<sup>2</sup> file to have:

```
set completion-display-width 0
```

to change the behavior for all new shells.

<sup><sup>1</sup> See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/344773/22523) for a method for controlling this behavior for individual custom completion functions.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> The search path for the readline init file is `$INPUTRC`, `~/.inputrc`, `/etc/inputrc` so modify the file appropriate for you.</sup>

Comment: wow, this is insanely simple! Well done. I'm gonna deeply test it, and I will come fwd.

Comment: Better late than never, right? ;) This is a native solution, and a great one. However, is there a way to achieve the `if more than X matches, go back to completion-display-width -1` with this? (@mkelement0 solution is working, but I'm curious about mixing both answers)

Comment: @4wk_ a little hacky but you can accomplish that with the technique from my [other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/344773/22523) I linked above, by changing `completion-display-width` during your function execution based on the number of matches generated and then have `PROMPT_COMMAND` set it back to the original value.